# Mapbox not accepting filter expression?

Tags: javascript, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to set a filter expression for a layer in which all features have a string-typed field within their properties named "iri". The expression should be a simple equality match, however Mapbox (v2.14.1) is producing an error that does not seem to correspond with the filter being passed in.

The filter object, as output to the console just before being passed to the map, is:

```
["==",["get","iri"],"some-iri-value"]
```

Error output from Mapbox:

```
evented.js:151 Error: layers.my-layer.filter: array expected, string found
    at bs (validate_style.js:13:41)
    at iA (style.js:64:5)
    at aA._validate (style.js:2234:16)
    at aA.setFilter (style.js:1647:18)
    at Map.setFilter (map.js:2720:20)
```

This is the correct syntax as far as I can tell, and it does work with style properties. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The error message you're seeing suggests that Mapbox is expecting an array for the filter expression, but it's receiving a string instead.

Comment: @vlanto, I understand that, but as far as all the documentation states this is the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is some type of timing issue, where everything isn't loaded at the time you call `setFilter`. If so, maybe you can use events of some kind to wait for loading:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function()
{
    // Initialize your Mapbox map here    
    map.on('load', function()
    {
        // Set your layer filters or any other map-specific functionality here
        map.setFilter('my-layer', ["==", ["get", "iri"], "some-iri-value"]);
    });
});
```